# Ajax.ActionLink() does not fire after putting htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to build list of hyperlink(ActionLink) from the collection. After applying htmlAttribute in following code, ActionLink does not trigger back to server.

```
   @foreach (MillitarySlot slot in item.MondaySlots)
    {
        @Ajax.ActionLink(linkText: @slot.SlotText,
        actionName: "CreateIndex",
        routeValues: new { someId = slot.Id },
        ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
        {
           UpdateTargetId = "divCreateSchedule",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "post"
        },
       //After adding following htmlAttribule, view does not trigger call
       htmlAttributes: new { title = slot.ToolTip, style = "color:" + slot.Color }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a bracket after slot.Color } for example..

```
   @foreach (MillitarySlot slot in item.MondaySlots)
{
    @Ajax.ActionLink(linkText: @slot.SlotText,
    actionName: "CreateIndex",
    routeValues: new { someId = slot.Id },
    ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
    {
       UpdateTargetId = "divCreateSchedule",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "post"
    },
   //After adding following htmlAttribule, view does not trigger call
   htmlAttributes: new { title = slot.ToolTip, style = "color:" + slot.Color })

}
```

Comment: The foreach loop is completed. There is no compilation error. While pasting the code I missed the last bracket token... :(

Comment: ok can you view the page source and let me know what html is generated for the link?

Comment: Thanks for track back! But, I took the path of jQuery instead of @Ajax.ActionLink and got something running. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686542/jquery-need-to-show-modal-dialog-on-any-anchor-link-click-on-the-page) for another post of this.